# Spring Boot with JPA can't find my databases

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Been trying to connect a fledgling Spring/JPA API to my PostgreSQL instance for a week now; I created a `properties` table in the `public` schema in pgAdmin AND `psql`, but even my test connections fail.

```
package com.mistermorse.cityofrefugejavaspringapi;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class CityOfRefugeJavaSpringApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        SpringApplication.run(CityOfRefugeJavaSpringApiApplication.class, args);
        String dbURL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/properties";
        String user = "postgres";
        String pass = "notActualPassword";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, pass);
    }

}
```

Here's the deal: I'm confident the database is there; running `\l` on `psql` returns a list containing `properties     | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 |`.

If I put a deliberate typo there, I get `Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgress"`, and I get `Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "properties" does not exist` if the login creds are right; I must be getting authenticated, at least. But, when I try to hit the database, I error out.

Am I missing a syntax error (maybe in the URL)? Am I implementing something incorrectly? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you say “hit the database, I error out”. Can you please add the code that hits the db? Note that the way you are connecting is very unusual for Spring Boot, which uses application.properties spring.datasource.

Comment: I'm just trying to hit it directly and simply; the code is just ```Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, pass);```.

Also, I know I will need to use ```application.properties```, but I'm trying to remove as many moving pieces as possible to get a proof of concept.

Comment: What does the **actual code** look like that fails? What is the stacktrace when it fails.

Comment: ```Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "properties" does not exist
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2676)
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readStartupMessages(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2788)
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.<init>(QueryExecutorImpl.java:174)
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:313)```

Comment: ```at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54)
 at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:253)
 at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:434)
 at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:291)
 at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681)
 at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229)
 at com.mistermorse.cityofrefugejavaspringapi.CityOfRefugeJavaSpringApiApplication.main(CityOfRefugeJavaSpringApiApplication.java:19)```

Answer (score 1):

It's obviously connecting to A database. I question if it's the correct one. Run `PGPASSWORD=password psql -U postgres -p 5432 -h localhost` and see if `\l` still gives you the database. I'm thinking there may be another instance on your machine running and jdnc is connecting to it.

Comment: Yep. Same list showing ```properties``` as above.